# How do I exclude images from Middleman blog post summaries?

Tags: middleman

Is there any easy way to keep images from showing up in [Middleman blog post summaries](http://middlemanapp.com/basics/blogging/#article-summaries)?

I have images that appear near the beginning of my post, and therefore appear in the summary. I would like for the summary to only include text.

I see that you can write your own summary generator, but I haven't learned Ruby yet. I'm hoping that this is a built-in option that I haven't come across yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try including `gem 'nokogiri'` into your Gemfile, running `bundle install` and starting your Middleman server with `bundle exec middleman server`.

Then you should be able to do `Nokogiri::HTML(article.summary).text` to retrieve text from summaries.

Comment: That is what I had to do to get article summaries to work, but is there a way to configure that to exclude images from the generated post summaries?